process a text file to modify a column value based on maximum value from another column
I have a file that i am looking to modify. There are 100's of files having the same issue. the input file is below
sample1 100A    total   1   1000
sample2 100A    total   1   5584
sample3 100A    total   1   8125
sample4 100A    total   1   59

sample1 .   year    1   1000
sample1 .   week1   20  1001
sample1 .   week2   50  1001

sample2 .   year    1   5584
sample2 .   week1   20  5585
sample2 .   week2   100 5585

sample3 .   year    1   8125
sample3 .   week1   55  8126
sample3 .   week2   100 8126

sample4 .   year    1   59
sample4 .   week1   10  59
sample4 .   week2   8   59

In the above file, where third column says "total" is the look up table and the maximum value for it should not exceed in any of the rows below for the respective samples.
For example, "sample1" has maximum value of 1000 but for "week1" and "week2" in third column has "1001" as maximum value. I see this happening for few rows for "week1 and week2" only and always its only 1 greater than maximum value. The output should be for both "week1" and "week2" rows should be updated to maximum value "1000". sample output below
sample1 100A    total   1   1000
sample2 100A    total   1   5584
sample3 100A    total   1   8125
sample4 100A    total   1   59
                
sample1 .   year    1   1000
sample1 .   week1   20  1000
sample1 .   week2   50  1000
                
sample2 .   year    1   5584
sample2 .   week1   20  5584
sample2 .   week2   100 5584
                
sample3 .   year    1   8125
sample3 .   week1   55  8125
sample3 .   week2   100 8125
                
sample4 .   year    1   59
sample4 .   week1   10  59
sample4 .   week2   8   59

Please provide me guidance on how should i proceed. I am a beginner programmer here looking to learn. thank you for your help

SO is (normally) not a place where you can find coders to do your job. It is a place where you can find help with your own code. Please show what you tried and explain what was wrong with it such that we can help you fixing it.

Please don't multi-post

Does this work for your use case?
(Assuming a tab-delimited input file)
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} /total/ {a[$1]=$5; print} !/total/ {print $1, $2, $3, $4, ($5 > a[$1] ? a[$1] : $5)}' input_file.txt

E.g.
cat input_file.txt
sample1 100A    total   1   1000
sample2 100A    total   1   5584
sample3 100A    total   1   8125
sample4 100A    total   1   59

sample1 .   year    1   1000
sample1 .   week1   20  1001
sample1 .   week2   50  1001

sample2 .   year    1   5584
sample2 .   week1   20  5585
sample2 .   week2   100 5585

sample3 .   year    1   8125
sample3 .   week1   55  8126
sample3 .   week2   100 8126

sample4 .   year    1   59
sample4 .   week1   10  59
sample4 .   week2   8   59

awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} /total/ {a[$1]=$5; print} !/total/ {print $1, $2, $3, $4, ($5 > a[$1] ? a[$1] : $5)}' input_file.txt
sample1 100A    total   1   1000
sample2 100A    total   1   5584
sample3 100A    total   1   8125
sample4 100A    total   1   59

sample1 .   year    1   1000
sample1 .   week1   20  1000
sample1 .   week2   50  1000

sample2 .   year    1   5584
sample2 .   week1   20  5584
sample2 .   week2   100 5584

sample3 .   year    1   8125
sample3 .   week1   55  8125
sample3 .   week2   100 8125

sample4 .   year    1   59
sample4 .   week1   10  59
sample4 .   week2   8   59


With nicer formatting:
awk 'BEGIN {
    FS = OFS = "\t"
}

/total/ {
    a[$1] = $5
    print
}

! /total/ {
    print $1, $2, $3, $4, ($5 > a[$1] ? a[$1] : $5)
}' input_file.txt


NB. Same approach, but if you have many columns in your input files and don't want to write out '$1, $2, etc':
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} /total/ {a[$1]=$5; print} !/total/ {if($5 > a[$1]){$5=a[$1]}; print}' input_file.txt


Thank you so much for your answer. When i am running with same input file, i am not getting the output you mentioned here. I am getting same as input file unchanged. Any pointers on where i am doing it wrong?

@bioiinffun try removing BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} from the script as your file may not be tab-separated, even though it does strongly look like it is, and removing that will let awk use any sequence of white space as the field separator.

Didn't think of that. as you mentioned, it looked like tab delimited only. Removing that worked
